# UIScrollView not scrolling iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am trying to create several UIScrollViews in a single view that scroll horizontally in iOS. This is my code so far:

```
-(void)updateSection {
    [feedLoadingActInd stopAnimating];
    feedLoadingActInd.hidden = YES;
    builder = [NSMutableArray array];
    float xPosition = 0;
    float xPosBut = 0;

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height - 29)];
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.delegate = self;

    for (int i = 0; i < itemArticleArray.count; i++) {
        testButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPosBut, 40, 40, 40)];
        [testButton setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [testButton setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        testButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        xPosBut += testButton.frame.size.width;
        NSLog(@"scroll.frame.size.width = %f", scrollView.frame.size.width);

        xPosition += 2;
        UIView *seperatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition, 4, 350, scrollView.frame.size.height - 8)];
        seperatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [scrollView addSubview:seperatorView];
        xPosition += 350;

        [seperatorView addSubview:testButton];
        [scrollView addSubview:seperatorView];
        [builder addObject:testButton];

    }
    [self addSubview:scrollView];
    [scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(xPosition, scrollView.frame.size.height)];

    NSLog(@"scroll.contentsize.width = %f", scrollView.contentSize.width);
```

}

However, none of the scroll views are actually scrolling, which I am confused about, as there are multiple buttons being added. Also, the buttons that I have added, are not actually doing anything when I press them. They should be running the buttonPressed method, and it doesn't?

Any help would be muchly appreciated!

Comment: You are setting your scroll view content size equal to the frame, so the component won't scroll. In order to scroll, scroll.contentSize.y > scroll.frame.height

Comment: [scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(xPosition, 700)];or you ajust with your height by generated buttons height

Comment: Made a slight mistake, and I need it to scroll horizontally not vertically

Comment: I've edited the post above and the code slightly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
float xPosition = 0;
    float xPosBut = 0;

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 29)];
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       UIButton *testButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition, 10, scrollView.frame.size.width, 50)];
        [testButton setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [testButton setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        testButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        xPosition += testButton.frame.size.width;
        NSLog(@"xposbut = %f", xPosBut);
        NSLog(@"scroll.frame.size.width = %f", scrollView.frame.size.width);

        xPosition += scrollView.frame.size.width+2;
        UIView *seperatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition, 4, 2, scrollView.frame.size.height - 8)];
        seperatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [scrollView addSubview:seperatorView];
        xPosition +=scrollView.frame.size.width+ 4;

        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
        [scrollView addSubview:seperatorView];
        [scrollView addSubview:testButton];
        [builder addObject:testButton];

    }
    [scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(xPosition, scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

set the for loop condition part as per your requirement.
hope this will help you.

Comment: If I change the line of code that says `scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 29)];` to this : `scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height - 29)];`
Then it doesn't let me scroll or press the button?